# How to create a textbox watermark?

Tags: html, watermark

I wish to create a textbox watermark without using either Ajax or JavaScript. How can I do this?

Comment: you should accept the answer if it helped - otherwise provide some feedback.

Comment: Without using JS your watermark will still be present even when text has been entered.

Answer (score 7):

It is very easy.
In html we can give the **placeholder** attribute for *input* elements.

**e.g.**

```
<input type="text" name="fst_name" placeholder="First Name"/>
```

check for more details :http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a background image with CSS like so.

```
textarea { 
    background-image: url(yourwatermarkimage); 
    background-attachment: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got a dll on this site. It solved my problem
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ASPNETandjQuery/Section1-TextBox/R12-TextBoxWaterMark.aspx

Comment: it works well, if you are submitting the text and dont enter anything, submit wont save any text.